# Is there a host function to convert half2 to float2 and vice versa?

Tags: cuda

In GPU, it is possible to easily convert `half2` to `float2` as follows:

```
float2 float2_value = __half22float2(half2_value);
```

Also, we can convert from `float2` to `half2`:

```
half2 half2_value = __float22half2_rn(float2_value);
```

I was wondering if it is possible to perform these operations on CPU when we need verification or when we need to prepare the data to send it to GPU.

Comment: http://half.sourceforge.net/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CUDA 10 [API reference](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-math-api/group__CUDA__MATH____HALF__MISC.html#group__CUDA__MATH____HALF__MISC) lists these functions as `__host__` `__device__`, meaning they are callable from host code:

> `__host__ ​ __device__` ​ __half2  __float22half2_rn ( const float2 a )
>   Converts both components of float2 number to half precision in round-to-nearest-even mode and returns half2 with converted values.
>
> `__host__ ​ __device__` ​ float2   __half22float2 ( const __half2 a )
>   Converts both halves of half2 to float2 and returns the result.

Here is a simple test case:

```
$ cat t308.cu
#include <cuda_fp16.h>
#include <iostream>

int main(){

  float2 a = make_float2(1.0, 2.0);
  half2 test =  __float22half2_rn ( a );
  a = make_float2(0.0, 0.0);
  std::cout << "a.x =  " << a.x << " a.y = " << a.y << std::endl;
  a = __half22float2( test );
  std::cout << "a.x =  " << a.x << " a.y = " << a.y << std::endl;
}
$ nvcc -o t308 t308.cu
$ ./t308
a.x =  0 a.y = 0
a.x =  1 a.y = 2
$
```

Comment: Thank you @Robert. I cannot compile them with CUDA 10. Have you tried them youself?

Comment: I've compiled the code successfully, exactly as you see here, under both CUDA 10.2 and CUDA 11.4

Answer (score 1):

I guess, [Robert](/users/1695960/robert-crovella) did *not* try to compile [his answer](/a/52969688/581002). He's right though that the [official documentation](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-math-api/group__CUDA__MATH____HALF__MISC.html#group__CUDA__MATH____HALF__MISC_1gc7bebc35ea0a149ccc35f214e623424c) claims that `__float22half2` is host callable. I ran into the same problem of not being able to do so. Digging through the sources, I find

```
__CUDA_FP16_DECL__ __half2 __float22half2_rn(const float2 f)
{
    __half2 val = __floats2half2_rn(f.x, f.y);
    return val;
}
```

where `#define __CUDA_FP16_DECL__ static __device__ __inline__`. So there's no `__host__` to be found and the compiler complains.

The only way I found is this one:

```
transform(begin(*kernel), end(*kernel), begin(*k), [](cuFloatComplex const cmplx)
{
    return half2{ half{cmplx.x}, half{cmplx.y} };
});
```

Answer (score 1):

As @primfaktor [noted](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55339213/2052436), Robert's code does not compile (in 10.2) despite documentation declaring `__float22half2_rn` as host and device.

However, you can find the following definition in another header (`cuda_fp16.hpp`)

```
__CUDA_HOSTDEVICE_FP16_DECL__ __half2 __float22half2_rn(const float2 f)
{
    __half2 val = __floats2half2_rn(f.x, f.y);
    return val;
}
```

Calling `__floats2half2_rn(f.x, f.y)` directly instead of `__float22half2_rn(f)` in host code worked for me.